Show that $p_0, \dots , p_m$ is a basis of $\mathcal{P}_m(F).$
Here is the question I am thinking of:
Suppose $m$ is a positive integer. For $0 \leq k \leq m,$ let $$p_k(x) = x^k(1-x)^{m - k},$$ Show that $p_0, \dots , p_m$ is a basis of $\mathcal{P}_m(F).$
I do not know what to do after assuming that $$\sum_{i=0}^{m}a_i x^i(1-x)^{m - i}=0 $$ can someone help me please?
Edit:
I found a solution here Let $n \in \mathbb{N}$ for all $k \in \{1,2...,n\}$ and $P_k=x^k(1-x)^{n-k}$. Prove that $\{P_0,...,P_n\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}_{n}[x]$ but still I do not understand how the proof of L.I can be done, it is not clearly explained.
Could someone explain this please?

Take a derivative, set $x$ to zero, set $x$ to one, repeat.

I do not understand, what is this technique? What are we doing? @GerryMyerson can you please explain more?

What is $F$? What is $\mathcal{P}_m(F)$? Please define your notation.

OK. Start by setting $x$ equal to zero (in your displayed formula). What do you get? By the way, if you can prove either linear independence or spanning, then the other follows automatically – do you know why?

yes I know :)@GerryMyerson

HINT.-Carefully develop $$\sum_{i=0}^{m}a_i x^i(1-x)^{m - i}=0$$ so you will get
$$A_mx^m +A_{m-1}x^{m-1}+A_{m-2}x^{m-2}+\cdots+A-1x+A_0=0$$ where each $A_k$ is a function of the coefficients $a_i$ and the equality is valid for all $x$ so this polynomial has more roots than its degree which means that each coefficient $A_k$ is equal to $0$. This yields a (linear) system of $m+1$ equations from which you have to deduce that each $a_i=0$.
Example for $m=3$
$$\sum_{i=0}^{3}a_i x^i(1-x)^{3 - i}=(-a_0+a_1-a_2+a_3)x^3+(3a_0-2a_1+a_2)x^2+(3a_0+a_1)x+a_0$$ Solving the system $$\begin{cases}-a_0+a_1-a_2+a_3=0\\3a_0-2a_1+a_2=0\\3a_0+a_1=0\\a_0=0\end{cases}$$ you get $a_i=0$ for $i=0,1,2,3$.
